# multiple functions with same name in clojure

Tags: clojure

```
(defn hi[](+ 5 6))  
(hi)  
(defn hi[](+ 6 7))  
(hi)
```

Hi,
i'm new to clojure . as above writen code i wrote two functions with same name.
can we have same name for multiple functions in clojure. if yes does it conflict within same namespaces?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm just checking whether it is correct to write multiple functions with same name. what if i had functions which does different operations and have same function name?

Comment: if the functions are different, they should have different names.

Comment: i wrote two functions which is shown above on same namespace. but still last expression is evaluated and i'm not getting any errors.

Comment: The second `defn` overwrites the first.

Comment: You may be confused that executing *all* the code above produces only one result - 13. Where did the 11 go to? In my repl, the above is surrounded by an implicit [`do`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(do%20exprs*)), hence returns the last evaluation, the 13 only. The repl evaluates the line(s) `1 2 "buckle my shoe"` to `"buckle my shoe"`.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot have several functions with the same name in the same namespace. If you define function `foo` and then redefine it again, newer version will replace the older.

It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but Clojure has quite a few ways to have several implementations under one name.

### Arity Dispatch

You can dispatch functions on arity:

```
(defn foo
  ([x] :version-one)
  ([x y] :version-two)
  ([x y & more] :version-tree))
```

Different arities of the same function can call one another, and this is somewhat equivalent to having several functions with the same name.

### Multimethods

You can dispatch using multimethods. They allow you to define a function that will be called on arguments and its result will be used for dispatching.

```
(defmulti foo odd?)

(defmethod foo true [x]
  (format "look, ma, %d is odd!" x))

(defmethod foo false [x]
  (format "look, ma, %d is even!" x))
```

### Protocols

This technique is similar to polymorphism in other languages. You can dispatch on argument type. Here is example:

```
(defprotocol foo
  (my-fnc [x] "description..."))

(extend-protocol foo
  Number
  (my-fnc [x] :number-version)
  String
  (my-fnc [x] :string-version))
```

Multimethods are most powerful tool, you can emulate protocols with them this way:

```
(defmulti foo class)
```

Comment: Also, you may be interested in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070368/clojure-multimethods-vs-protocols).

Answer (score 1):

*I wrote two functions with same name.*

Yes and No:

- You wrote two function definitions with the same name.
- The second definition overwrote the first.
- The functions never shared the name.

*Can we have same name for multiple functions in clojure?*

Not in the same namespace. A second `def` or `defn` for a symbol erases the first.

- There is only one symbol with a given name in a namespace.
- A *symbol* refers to only one `var` at a time.
- [The `def` form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(def%20symbol%20init?)) ties a symbol to the `var` it refers to.
- [The `fn` form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(fn%20name?%20[params*%20]%20exprs*)) creates a function.
- The `defn` macro is a wrapper round    the `def` and `fn` forms,
  causing the named symbol to refer to a `var` holding the function.
- Symbols with the same name in different namespaces do not conflict: 
  they are different symbols.

*If yes does it conflict within the same namespace?*

Yes.

*But ...*

One *function* can have several arities - argument counts. This applies to functions referred to by symbols through vars and in other contexts.

---

Function definition is a *side-effect* of evaluating a `defn`. The best explanation I know of how lisps *evaluate* function definitions is Chapter 2 of [Paul Graham's *On Lisp*](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf).