# Canonical approach to return based on type of the argument in Clojure

Tags: clojure

If the argument is a symbol return it. If the argument is a list call another method.

New to Clojure and cannot find the canonical way to do it. In Python, one could do:

```py
def return_on_arg_type(arg):
  if type(arg) is str:
    return arg
  if type(arg) is list:
    return another_method(arg)
```

May be I could use multi-methods but how to match on type of the argument and also is matching on type acceptable in Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's essentially 3 dispatch methods in Clojure:

1. Use `cond` combined with predicates (that's methods that return true or false and often have a name ending in `?`) as Alan has described.
2. Use Protocols which dispatch on the type of the first argument. The reference documentation for this would be at https://clojure.org/reference/protocols
3. Multimethods. You can think of Multimethods as a programmable dispatch method. They can do much more than just look at the type of their arguments, they could also look into arguments, count elements on a vector argument and much more. Canonical documentation at https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods

Take a look at [Clojure multimethods vs. protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070368/clojure-multimethods-vs-protocols) for a short discussion on Multimethods vs Protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the goal, but this should work:

```
(defn something [arg]
  (cond
    (str? arg)  arg
    (list? arg) (other-fn arg)))
```

Comment: It works! The other part of the question is: are there better approaches (more idiomatic to the language) to do the same thing?

Comment: `cond` is idiomatic enough. You could also try `cond->`

Comment: This is totally idiomatic, in that it is totally simple and obvious. Non-toy problems might demand protocols or multimethods but this does not.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to check for types in Clojure. It is not an un-typed language.

The code proposed by Alan is idiomatic IMHO if you need a simple dispatch mechanism.
There are other possibilities here. One you mentioned already: multi-methods.
Your example could be written as

```
(defmulti something class [arg])
(defmethod something String [arg] arg)
(defmethod something java.util.List [arg] (some-other arg))
```

The dispatch fn is `class` in this case, but you can implement any kind of dispatch condition.

There's also `clojure.match`, a general purpose matching library (among others). See https://github.com/clojure/core.match

Answer (score 0):

Next to using a multimethod or a method to explicitly check, it's also possible to dispatch on the type of first argument with a protocol:

```
(defprotocol OnArgTypeReturner
  (return-on-arg-type [arg]))

(extend-protocol OnArgTypeReturner
  String
  (return-on-arg-type [arg] arg)
  clojure.lang.IPersistentList
  (return-on-arg-type [arg] "another-method-called"))

(return-on-arg-type "foo")
;; => "foo"

(return-on-arg-type '(1 2 3))
;; => "another-method-called"
```